# Core Data: How to Create a Persistent Document with Singleton Entity?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, core-data

I have a swift application which uses core data to store a document. Each document contains one entity `Settings` where exactly one instance of this entity shall exist in each document.

The instance should automatically created for each new document and be accessible if an existing document is opened.

**How should I implement such a core data application?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to implement a such singleton entity is using a special getter which checks and creates the entity if needed.

```
class Document: NSPersistentDocument {
    var settings: Settings {
        if _settings == nil {
            do {
                let fetchSettings = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Settings")
                let settingsList = try self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchSettings)
                precondition(settingsList.count < 2, "Too many settings object in the core data store.")
                if settingsList.count == 1 {
                    self._settings = settingsList[0] as? Settings
                    precondition(self._settings != nil)
                } else {
                    self._settings = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Settings", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as? Settings
                    precondition(self._settings != nil)
                    // init the settings object here
                    self.managedObjectContext!.processPendingChanges()
                    self.managedObjectContext!.undoManager!.removeAllActions()
                }
            } catch {
                preconditionFailure("Could not retrieve/create settings object because of an unknown core data error.")
            }
        }
        return _settings!
    }
    private var _settings: Settings?
    // ...
}
```

The class `Settings` in this example is a subclass of `NSManagedObject` to simplify access to the values of the object. You can use `NSManagedObject` directly instead of a own class.

The class `Document` has a private property `_settings` which holds the current instance of the `Settings` entity. The getter `settings` checks this variable, and if no instance is set the managed object context is checked for the entity.

```
let fetchSettings = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Settings")
let settingsList = try self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchSettings)
```

First a list of all `Settings` entities is fetched from the context.

```
if settingsList.count == 1 {
    self._settings = settingsList[0] as? Settings
    precondition(self._settings != nil)
} else {
```

This list is checked if there is already an existing `Settings` entity. In this case the existing entity is used.

```
self._settings = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Settings", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as? Settings
precondition(self._settings != nil)
// init the settings object here
```

If no `Settings` entity exists, a new one is created and initialised with the default values.

```
self.managedObjectContext!.processPendingChanges()
self.managedObjectContext!.undoManager!.removeAllActions()
```

This two lines remove any undo actions which were created initialising the new `Settings` entity. It is necessary to make sure a new document does not start with the "edited" flag. It also makes sure that an initial undo will not delete the created `Settings` object.

It is important that the `settings` attribute is accessed as soon as possible, before any user interaction is done. Otherwise the interface will have a problem with the undo actions. Best is to access the `settings` getter in the `document` property of the `NSWindowController` of the document window:

```
override var document: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // access the `settings` property of the document.
    }
}
```

### Why Not Put Everything Into `Document.init()`?

It is possible to initialise data for the document in the `init()` method, but at this point the managed object context is still empty. You have to wait until the initialisation of the document has finished, before you can check if a `Settings` object exists in the managed object context.

### Can Undo be Disabled Instead of Removing All Actions?

This really depends on the rest of the implementation of the application. But it is easily possible using code like this:

```
self.managedObjectContext!.processPendingChanges()
self.managedObjectContext!.undoManager!.disableUndoRegistration()
self._settings = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Settings", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as? Settings
precondition(self._settings != nil)
// init the settings object here
self.managedObjectContext!.processPendingChanges()
self.managedObjectContext!.undoManager!.enableUndoRegistration()
```

Comment: It is possible to disable undo temporarily instead of removing the undo actions. The settings object can be created later on.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, this is possible. I added the some details to my answer. The outcome really depends on the rest of your application. Important are the two `processPendingChanges()` to make sure everything is processed in a sequential order.